# CutyCapt with php exec

Tags: php, cutycapt

I'am using CutyCapt on my CentOS.
It works fine via terminal but it doesn't work via php exec function.
I've started xvfb by command in terminal:

```
Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1024x768x24
```

And I'am trying to do a screenshot by php script:

```
exec("DISPLAY=:99 /path/to/cutycapt --url=<some url> --out=<path/to/output>");
```

It doesn't show any errors but there is no output file (output directory has chmod 777)
Can somebody help me?

Thanks

**UPD:**
Maybe it is better somehow  to allow executing of Xvfb by Apache?

Comment: Try with the following code and post results.

`$output = array();
$return_var = null;
$result = exec("DISPLAY=:99 /path/to/cutycapt --url=<some url> --out=<path/to/output>", $output, $return_var);

var_dump($result);
var_dump($output);
var_dump($return_var);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to get CutyCapt to run successfully using the php at the end.  The $_parameters are passed via AJAX to the php script.  Hope this helps...

```
 case 'Output_Chart': {

    // We always create the .png.  We use the  ImageMagick convert (IMC) command to make .pdfs
    if ($_Suffix == 'pdf') {
       $IMC = ";convert -page 735x850 '$_PathOut/$_ChartName.png' '$_PathOut/$_ChartName.pdf'";
    } else {
       $IMC = '';
    }

    // Prepare the query string for the CutyCapt URL
    $sQuery_Pattern   = '?Path=%s&iDL=%d';
    $sQuery           = sprintf($sQuery_Pattern, $_Path, $_iDL);

    // Prepare CutyCapt's command and parameters (NB: query string and out parameter are enclosed in aposts for the shell)
    $sCC_Cmd          = '/var/www/LF/Includes/CutyCapt';
    $sCC_URL          = "http://localhost/LF/LFPrint.html'$sQuery'";     // Note: Inner apostrophes
    $sCC_Out          = "'$_PathOut/$_ChartName.png'";
    $sCC_Pattern      = ' --url=%s --out=%s --delay=%d --min-width=%d';
    $sCC_Options      = sprintf($sCC_Pattern, $sCC_URL, $sCC_Out, $_Delay, $_MinWidth);
    //$sCC_CmdLine         = $sCC_Cmd . $sCC_Options . " 2> CutyCapt.err.txt";
    $sCC_CmdLine         = $sCC_Cmd . $sCC_Options . " 2> /dev/null";

    // Prepare the final command line with xvfb-run, CutyCapt, and the URL?QueryString
    $sCC_CmdLine = 'xvfb-run --auto-servernum --server-args="-screen 0, 800x1000x24" ' . $sCC_CmdLine . $IMC;
    exec( $sCC_CmdLine, $aOutput = array(), $ret);
    // Wait for and then return the results.  sCC_CmdLine and aOutput are just for debugging
    echo json_encode(array("ret" => $ret, "cmd" => $sCC_CmdLine, "Output" => $aOutput));
    break;
 }
```